# Putting image in column of a table

Tags: html, css, jsp, html-table

I was trying to put a image inside a column of a table.
My code for each table row is :

```
<tr bgcolor="#5D7B9D" color="#FFFFFF" onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true,true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false,true);" onclick="DoNav('showdrivefile.jsp?shid=<%=sharingid%>&fileid=<%=fileid%>&sendername=<%=filesendername%>&senderid=<%=filesender%>');">    
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="DoRemove(event);"  width="20" class="select_all_mail" value=<%=sharingid%>></td>

//The problem is here,When i insert the image the jsp page starts giving an error.I have two images and each image is put if condition is satisfied.

<%if(filesendername.compareTo(userrname)==0){%>
<td><img src="images/mail-outbox.png" width="30"></td>
<%}%>
<%else if(filesendername.compareTo(userrname)!=0){%>
<td><img src="images/mail_inbox.png" width="30"></td>
<%}%>
<td callspan="3" width="1000px"><%=filesendername%>  :   <%=sharingsubject%>      <%=sharingtime%></td>
</tr>
```

What can be the problem? If I don't insert the image the code runs fine. Please help

A small part of my error :

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: The code looks ok.  What's the error you're getting.

Comment: add an image if possible of what' your output or log of error

Comment: @Frakcool I added a part of my stackTrace.Please check and help

Comment: keep looking at it, it's correct, but why that error... My only guesses by now are `images/mail-outbox.png` and `images/mail_inbox.png` your images names are those? I mean "underscore" and "score" ? maybe that's the error. Check it

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the problem, but you did not properly close your `<img>` tag. Instead of:

```
<td><img src="images/mail-outbox.png" width="30"></td>
```

it should be

```
<td><img src="images/mail-outbox.png" width="30"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%if(filesendername.equalsIgnoreCase(userrname)){%>
<td><img src="images/mail-outbox.png" width="30" /></td>
<%}
 else
 {
%>
<td><img src="images/mail_inbox.png" width="30"></td>
<%}%>
```